# How to implement method getFilter for ListAdapter

Tags: java, android

I want to implement a search feature in a mobile application named medical-u, an application in medicine that has a search feature for searching hospitals and general practitioners (puskesmas in Indonesian). I want to add the search feature using EditText on a ListView.
In the tutorials and documentation on the internet, the Adapter used is the `ArrayAdapter`, while in my project I use a `ListAdapter`, and the search list retrieves data from a Jakarta URL API.
The `getFilter` in the documentation only applies to the `ArrayAdapter` in all tutorials and free documentation, whereas what I use here is the getFilter method for the `ListAdapter`.

```
public class RumahSakitMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar pbMain;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listrs;
    //ori "http://api.jakarta.go.id/v1/rumahsakitumum/"
    //cadangan "https://api.jakarta.go.id/v1/rumahsakitumum/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30?format=geojson"
    String url = "http://api.jakarta.go.id/v1/rumahsakitumum/";
    SearchView svs;

    // Edit Search Text
    private EditText searchText;

    ListAdapter ladapter ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rumah_sakit_main);

        // date
        TextView tanggal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tanggal);
        SimpleDateFormat formattgl = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        String currentDateandTime = formattgl.format(new Date());
        tanggal.setText("Penarikan Data Terakhir :\n"+currentDateandTime);

        // hospital search text
        searchText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);

        // hospital list
        listrs = new ArrayList<>();
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDaftar);
        pbMain = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingBar);
        pbMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RumahSakitMain.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        // refresh button
        Button btnRefreshRS = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRefreshRS);

        btnRefreshRS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent refresh = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tungguRS.class);
                startActivity(refresh);
                RumahSakitMain.this.finish();
            }
        });

        View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
        lv.addFooterView(footerView, null, false);

        //Volley, untuk penarikan data dari API, week 11
        RequestQueue q = Volley.newRequestQueue(RumahSakitMain.this);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // get JSON data, week 11
                try {
                   // String judul = "Rumah Sakit";
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray data = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject a = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        String judul = a.getString("jenis_rsu");
                        String namars = a.getString("nama_rsu");
                        String id = a.getString("id");
                        String kode_pos = a.getString("kode_pos");
                        String email = a.getString("email");
                        String website = a.getString("website");


                        JSONObject b = a.getJSONObject("location");
                        String alamatrs = b.getString("alamat");

                        JSONArray c = a.getJSONArray("telepon");
                        String telepon = (String) c.get(0);

                        // Week 11
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("id", id);
                        map.put("namaRS", namars);
                        map.put("jenis", judul);
                        map.put("alamatRS", alamatrs);
                        map.put("kodepos", kode_pos);
                        map.put("email", email);
                        map.put("website", website);
                        map.put("telepon", telepon);
                        map.put("id", id);
                        listrs.add(map);
                    }
                    pbMain.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    ladapter = new SimpleAdapter(RumahSakitMain.this, listrs, R.layout.layoutdaftar, new String[]{"jenis", "namaRS", "alamatRS", "telepon"}, new int[]{R.id.judulnya, R.id.txtNama, R.id.txtAlamat, R.id.txtTelepon});
                    lv.setAdapter(ladapter);

                    Toast.makeText(RumahSakitMain.this, "Penarikan Data Berhasil!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Traffic API padat ", e.toString());
                    pbMain.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    RumahSakitMain.this.finish();
                    Intent traffic = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), trafficRS.class);
                    startActivity(traffic);
/*
                    dialog.setTitle("Kendala Teknis!");
                    dialog.setMessage("Penarikan data dari server pusat gagal!");
                    dialog.setPositiveButton("Refresh", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //finish();
                            //System.exit(0);
                            Intent refresh = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RumahSakitMain.class);
                            startActivity(refresh);
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.setNegativeButton("Kembali ke Menu Utama", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent utama = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(utama);
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();
                    */

                }

            }


        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Internet tidak aktif", error.toString());

                RumahSakitMain.this.finish();

                Intent internet = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internetRS.class);
                startActivity(internet);

                /*
                dialog.setTitle("Gagal Terhubung!");
                dialog.setMessage("Cek Koneksi Internet Anda!");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Refresh", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //finish();
                        //System.exit(0);
                        Intent refresh = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RumahSakitMain.class);
                        startActivity(refresh);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Kembali ke Menu Utama", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent utama = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(utama);
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
                */

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/geojson");
                params.put("Authorization", "Jii+apzvYMt2DWzwEYUvLM4ClHAH1JbE5ro/9eQYpOyvVoaykaOGzwHrU2s/Xyr8\n");
                return params;
            }
        };
        q.add(sr);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String nama = listrs.get(position).get("namaRS");
                String alamat = listrs.get(position).get("alamatRS");
                String telp = listrs.get(position).get("telepon");
                String web = listrs.get(position).get("website");
                String email = listrs.get(position).get("email");
                String judul = listrs.get(position).get("jenis");

                //detail fraga = new detail();
                //Bundle args = new Bundle();
                //args.putString("nama",nama);
                //args.putString("alamat",alamat);
                //args.putString("telp",telp);
                //args.putString("web",web);
                //args.putString("email",email);
                //fraga.setArguments(args);

                Intent keDetail = new Intent(RumahSakitMain.this, RumahSakitDetail.class);
                keDetail.putExtra("jenis", judul);
                keDetail.putExtra("nama", nama);
                keDetail.putExtra("alamat", alamat);
                keDetail.putExtra("telp", telp);
                keDetail.putExtra("web", web);
                keDetail.putExtra("email", email);
                startActivity(keDetail);

                //    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                //   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                // ft.replace(R.id.frame,fraga);
                //ft.addToBackStack(null);
                //ft.commit();

                //Intent intent = new Intent(RumahSakitMain.this, RumahSakitDetail.class);
                //intent.putExtra("data", json.toString());
                //startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

So, I want to know how to implement `getFilter` function for `ListAdapter`, because usually it is used for `ArrayAdapter`. When I use `getFilter` for `ListAdapter`, it shows "cannot resolve method getFilter()", so, how to write `getFilter` function for ListAdapter? But the problem we can't change the List Adapter into another Adapter, because it make the program error. How to make function getFilter fo List Adapter without changing any Adapter?

```
        searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                // the error is on getFilter(), because it's red colored
                // it show "cannot resolve method getFilter"
                RumahSakitMain.this.ladapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RumahSakitMain.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Menu ");
        dialog.setMessage("Apa yang ingin Anda lakukan?");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Refresh", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //finish();
                //System.exit(0);
                Intent refresh = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tungguRS.class);
                startActivity(refresh);
                Toast.makeText(RumahSakitMain.this, "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                RumahSakitMain.this.finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Kembali ke Menu Utama", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent utama = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(utama);
                RumahSakitMain.this.finish();
            }
        });

        dialog.setNeutralButton("Batal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(RumahSakitMain.this, "Batal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a custom Adapter. Create an adapter that extends ListAdapter and implement getFilter() yourself.

Comment: Then, how can I make custom adapter for List Adapter?

Comment: If you only need this to filter what's displayed in the `ListView`, you can just use `ArrayAdapter`'s source as a guide: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java. The `ArrayFilter` class and the `getFilter()` method are at the end. If this is only being used in your code, then those two things are all you really need, but if you use your `Adapter` with some certain framework APIs, then you might have to `implements Filterable`, too, which is just the `getFilter()` method.